# I am attempting write a class that multiplies two matrices using arrays. Are there any errors in the code?

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class Matrix {
    public static float[][] multiplyM(float[][] FM, float[][] SM) throws IOException{
        int Frows = FM.length;
        int Fcolumns = FM[0].length;
        int Srows = FM[0].length;
        int Scolumns = FM.length;
        System.out.println(Frows);
        System.out.println(Fcolumns);
        System.out.println("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$");
        System.out.println(Srows);
        System.out.println(Scolumns);



        int z;
        int dd;
        float finAns[][] = new float[Fcolumns][Scolumns];
        if (Scolumns != Frows){
            System.out.println("ERROR!!!");
        }
        else{
            int rNum = 0;
            int cNum = 0;

            //compute matrix
            for (dd = 0; dd < Frows; dd++){

                //compute row in matrix
                for (z = 0; z < Scolumns; z++){

                    //compute element in matrix
                    for (int i = 0; i < Fcolumns ; i++){

                        finAns[dd][z] += FM[dd][i] * SM[i][z];

                    }//end of for 1
                }//end of for 2
            }//end of for 3

        }
        int Finrows = finAns.length;
        int Fincolumns = finAns[0].length;
        System.out.println(Finrows);
        System.out.println(Fincolumns);
        System.out.println("*************");

        return finAns;

    }
    /*
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        float [][] a = {{3,4,7,},{4,4,3},{4,7,6}};
        float [][] b = {{3,4,8},{4,4,2},{2,9,0}};
        multiplyM(a,b);
    }
     */
}
```

Comment: `"Are there any errors...?"` -- what happens when you test the code? Is it compiling? Running? Is its output what you expect it should be?

Comment: Please post input/ output /errors

Comment: This question may be closed for not showing the results of your own prior research and debugging result. In moving forward, please go through the [tour] and do take a look at the [help] section as well as the [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section, so that your questions and answers will be better making your future experiences here better.

Comment: I suspect that printing out a float array isn't going to work this way; other than that, the code doesn't look too awful.

Comment: This is the error message: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int Frows = FM.length;
int Fcolumns = FM[0].length;
int Srows = FM[0].length;
int Scolumns = FM.length;
```

should be

```
int Frows = FM.length;
int Fcolumns = FM[0].length;
int Srows = FM.length;
int Scolumns = FM[0].length;
```

and ...

```
float finAns[][] = new float[Fcolumns][Scolumns];
```

should be

```
float finAns[][] = new float[Frows][Scolumns];
```

Start with that